# Get the current directory of the launched bat issue

Tags: batch-file

I have a bat file `mybat.bat` in a folder `Myfolder`

I want to set the current directory to `Myfolder` path

If I try

```
@echo on
cd\%0

pause
```

I get as current directory

```
Myfolder\mybat.bat
```

but I need only

```
Myfolder
```

How should I edit my bat to fix the problem?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You want either

```
 cd /d "%~dp0"
```

or

```
 pushd "%~dp0"
```

Answer (score 0):

This is another method:

```
cd  Myfolder\mybat.bat\..
```